# Handle data in ViewModel and Fragment in MVVM

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-viewmodel

I've seen quite a lot of tutorials but didn't really managed to get myself to properly understand how to handle some cases in MVVM.

Let's say that there is a repository that fetches data from a `DAO` which uses `Room`

```
class Repository(){

  fun getItems() = itemsDAO.getItems()

}
```

A ViewModel that queries the Repository

```
class FragmentViewModel:ViewModel(){

    val items = repository.getItems()

    fun updateItem(Item item){
       repository.updateImte(itemm)
    }
}
```

And a fragment

```
class MyFragment:Fragment(){

   //onViewCreated
   viewModel.items.observe(...){
        //if result, update the views
     }

  buttonUpdateItem.setOnClickListener{
    viewModel.updateItem(Item item)    
  }

}
```

This is the approach I understood from tutorials. Basically I have some things to clarify and I would like to ask for your help.

a. Given this implementation of the `ViewModel` if the user rotates the device and the fragment gets recreated, doesn't this mean that the database will be queried again when `observe` will be added?
I am thinking of an updated version of ViewModel like

```
  class FragmentViewModel:ViewModel(){
        private final var itemsObservable;


       init {
           itemsObservable = repository.getItems()
        }

       fun items(){
           return itemsObservable
       }

        fun updateItem(Item item){
           repository.updateImte(item)
        }
    }
```

If I am right, this should allow to return the initial values from db and not call again the db in case of fragment recreation.

b. How should the `ViewModel` act on the `Fragment` interraction, more precise on button click event? Should the `fragment` as in the sample above, call the `viewModel.updateItem` function or the `viewModel` should return a `onClickListener` variable which should be set to the button?

c. should the arguments passed to the `fragment` also be added to the `ViewModel`?

d. As you can see, the `ViewModel` holds variable for `LiveData<List<>>` so for instance, if I want to update an item, then the `fragment` passes that `Item`. Is this a good approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First I would like to point you to
[Android Architecture Blueprints](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture) on GitHub:

> The focus of this project is on demonstrating how to structure your
>   code, design your architecture, and the eventual impact of adopting
>   these patterns on testing and maintaining your app. You can use the
>   techniques demonstrated here in many different ways to build apps.
>   Your own particular priorities will impact how you implement the
>   concepts in these projects, so you should not consider these samples
>   to be canonical examples.

These are the official examples of different architectures in Android, you should definitely check that out as an inspiration for you own projects.

a. Your updated version is the correct way to do this - to retrieve a list of items, invoke the repository method once and store the return value in the `ViewModel`. Use `LiveData<List<Item>>` as a return value in your DAO and Room will automatically notify your `Observer` in the `Fragment` of any changes.

b. `ViewModel` can have the `updateItem(item: Item)` method. The `onClickListener` should be placed in the `Fragment`. You might want to do some validation in the `Fragment` as well before invoking the `updateItem` method. Also it is important to not hold any `View` references in the `ViewModel`.
To notify the `Fragment` about the update status, you might consider having another `LiveData` field in the `ViewModel` (for example `errorMessage: LiveData<Int>`) and assign it the `R. id` of the string resource you would like to display. This way you move the logic of determining the specific message to display from the `Fragment` to the `ViewModel`.

c. You only need some arguments in the `ViewModel`. For instance, when you have an id extra argument passed to the `Fragment` in a `Bundle`, you would init the `ViewModel` with this id to load the item.

d. Passing the `Item` can definitely be a good approach. You can also consider creating a Presenter to separate some logic out of the `Fragment` (so it does not work with the `Item`). You will find more information and examples on the GitHub link above.

So I think there are different approaches to choose from depending on the app you are developing. Testing is very important and after implementing one approach you will find how it affects the ease of writing your tests. But this is how I see the answers for your questions.

Comment: Awesome answer. Thank you for your time and detailed info.

Comment: @Alin No problem, happy to help!

Comment: Here's something interesting regarding the ViewModel with using `Init`. In Android Studio if I use the `init`, I get suggestion that variable "Can be joined with assignment" so if I apply it, it ends with the same as before...

Comment: Right, in this simple case you can join it if the `repository` field is already initialized, you still only execute the repository method once. But maybe you would like to use dependency injection and inject the repository in the constructor. Then you would need to initialize the `items` field there. So the bottom line is that you only want to assign it once.